Receive price onchain
I want receive price of SOL from pyth network:
let price_account_info = &ctx.accounts.sol_price_feed;
let sol_price_feed = load_price_feed_from_account_info(&price_account_info).unwrap();
let current_timestamp = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;
let current_price = sol_price_feed
   .get_price_no_older_than(current_timestamp, STALENESS_THRESHOLD)
   .unwrap();

when  I try:
"Error: Simulation failed. \nMessage: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Program failed to complete


You'll need to provide some more info, like what account you're passing in, and what library you're using to deserialize the account
